# Does scanning Pinnacle Station give you anything different if you did the DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the Phoenix system of the Argus Rho cluster, you can find Pinnacle Station. Scanning it gave me a Turian Spec Ops Team worth 40 War Assets.

I didn't actually *do* the Pinnacle Station DLC for Mass Effect 1, so I'd like to know if there is something I'm missing out on by not having done it. Is the worth of the War Assets higher if you've done it? Do you get something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you completed (or owned) the Pinnacle Station DLC seems to have no impact, as the reward is the same in both cases.